# Enable Drill Down according to User access in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am basically trying to create a report where I need to take average of employees attendance per year and in another report I need to create an AVG(Attendance) for employees for each month.

### So

Report 1:(Attendance Per year)

Parameters:

```
    (Year)     Attendance (=100%, >=95% and <100%,>=90% and <95%,>=80% and <90% )
```

### |EMPID  |  EMP_Name| AVG(Attendance)|

Report 2(Attendance per month)

```
    (Year)     (EMPID)

         |EMPID  |  EMP_Name| AVG(Attendance)|
```

My question is can I just create one report and have Report 2 as a drill Down and have only users with certain privileges access the details (Report 2 )  .

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the user from User!UserID, and use that to look up an access level.  Then you can make the drilldown visible or invisible depending on user access.  That should make it possible to control access to the drilldown.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875939/reporting-services-2008-using-useruserid-in-parameters).

Does this help?

Comment: Hmm can I make just the Drill Down accessible to some and the the the other users not to access the drill down.

Comment: Try turning the visibility on and off, @snp.it.  If necessary, put the drilldown in a separate row that you can make visible or invisible.  You can use a separate query and dataset to tell you whether the current user has access or not.