# SSRS - Checking the UserID before allowing execution of report

Tags: reporting-services

I am using this code at the top of the SQL in my dataset for an SSRS report:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ValidUsers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ValidUsers
CREATE TABLE #ValidUsers
(
    ValidUsers          Varchar(100),
)

Insert Into #ValidUsers SELECT 'ABC\UserA'
Insert Into #ValidUsers SELECT 'ABC\UserB'
Insert Into #ValidUsers SELECT 'ABC\UserC'
```

Then, I have this code that, at run time, pulls the current UserID into a variable @CurrentUser and I check if @CurrentUser is in my #ValidUsers temp table:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ValidUsers WHERE ValidUsers = @CurrentUser)
Begin
... run SQL to retrieve data ...
Else
... don't retrieve the data ...
End
```

This is working just fine and only the users I specifically insert into #ValidUsers are able to run the report.

Is this acceptable - or is it a bad/insecure way to limit who can run an SSRS report?

If it is not good, what is the recommended way to restrict who can run a report?

Comment: Only you can determine if it is bad - does it accomplish what you require? My only question would be why not use the built in security settings?

Comment: Agreed, Reporting Services has built in security that can determine who is able to view/run reports/folders.  No harm in using SQL as a secondary check but I don't see the point.

Comment: It does accomplish what I require ["This is working just fine ..."]. Can you please give me a pointer to what I should search for regarding built in security settings? I have not used these and don't know where/how to set them.

Comment: @Talay have you tried the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/reporting-services-security-and-protection?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `user dataset` in your report, then filter it by `where name=@CurrentUser` (set @CurrentUser's  default value  to User!UserID) in report. When the current user is in `user dataset`, the report will show, if its not in it, the report will show blank.

You could refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875939/reporting-services-2008-using-useruserid-in-parameters)  for details.

Comment: I am already doing this inside my dataset by creating the #ValidUsers temp table. Thanks!